# Update WooCommerce stock status with SQL query if stock value is greater than 0

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm attempting to update a large product catalogue using a SQL query via phpMyAdmin if:

1. the `_stock_status` = `onbackorder`
2. the `_stock` > 0

**Queries attempted:**

```
Update wp_postmeta 
Set meta_value = 'instock' 
Where meta_key = '_stock' 
And meta_value > 0
```

---

```
Update wp_postmeta 
Set meta_value = 'instock' 
Where meta_value = 'onbackorder' 
And meta_key = '_stock_status'
And meta_value > 0
And meta_key = "_stock"
```

---

```
Update wp_postmeta 
Set meta_value = 'instock' 
Where meta_value = 'onbackorder' 
And '_stock' > 0
```

None of the above have worked.
The last query reduces all stock quantities to 0 but the stock status remains on "backorder"

Comment: How large is the product catalog? This might be easier to do in PHP

Comment: @czerspalace Around 2000 products.

Comment: the data you are comparing are in different rows, so you will have to do a join to get the correct data, or in WP you can get the products `$products = wc_get_products( array( 'stock_status' => 'backorder' ) );` and in the loop update as needed

Comment: @czerspalace complete sql novice here, any chance you could show me what that sql query (with the join) would look like and I'll iterate and test?

Comment: this answer might help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172041/can-wp-query-return-posts-meta-in-a-single-request/256363#256363