# Get attachment by meta_key value

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, attachments, meta-query

I need to get the attachment (will be only one per post) associated to a post with meta_key `wpcf-legislacion-gratis` (not matter the value the column has) by using a custom query using `get_posts()` function. I've tried this two ways:

```
$nonActivePlan_args   = array(
    'order'           => 'desc',
    'meta_query'          => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'wpcf-legislacion-gratis',
                'value'   => NULL,
                'compare' => '!='
            )
    ),
    'post_status'         => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
);

$nonActivePlanAttachment = get_posts( $nonActivePlan_args );
if ($nonActivePlanAttachment) {
    foreach ($nonActivePlanAttachment as $attachment) { ?>
        <div class="legislacion-ico">
            <a class="pdf" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, true ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ico_descargas.png">
                <br>
                Descargar PDF
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Related to the one above I have this doubts:

- How do I write the query for find the attachment with meta_key equal to `wpcf-legislacion-gratis` not matter what values it has?
- Is the loop on this case the right one? Notice I'll only have one `wpcf-legislacion-gratis` per post so do I need to loop over the results? Shouldn't be just one?
- If I'll get both attachment separated (as you will see in the query at the end of the post) should I execute `wp_reset_postdata()`?

I've tried also this code:

```
$nonActivePlan_args   = array(
    'order'             => 'desc',
    'meta_key'          => 'wpcf-legislacion-gratis',
    'post_status'       => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'       => get_the_ID(),
);
```

But is not working meaning I don't get any value from DB. This is the result of query I've executed on the MySQL command line:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` where post_id='11839';
+---------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key                | meta_value                                                                        |
+---------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   22149 |   11839 | wpcf-legislacion-gratis | http://jurisprudencia.dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/modelodatos.pdf              |
|   22150 |   11839 | wpcf-legislacion-pagada | http://jurisprudencia.dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/AtencionUsuario_version1.pdf |
+---------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have also checked docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) but didn't found any helpful to me.

How do I get the attachment? Any help or advice?

Comment: Is this on a single post page

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes, it's in a `single-legislacion.php`

Comment: Any reason why you are running a custom query instead of using `get_post_meta()`

Comment: @PieterGoosen not at all, can you provide an example? How to get the same but using `get_post_meta()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is `get_post_meta()`  and not a custom query.

### REASONS:

- The results from custom fields are cached and extremely streamline when it cone to performance. You can read [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167151/31545) I have done recently which will explain everything
- You are trying to get the custom field attached to a post only in a single post page. This is what `get_post_meta()` was designed for

You can replace all your code with something like this: (*Modified from the codex*)

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-legislacion-gratis', true ); 
// check if the custom field has a value 
if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) { 
    echo $key_1_value; 
}
```

### EDIT

If you need to get the custom field value outside the loop like in a sidebar or function, you need to replace `get_the_ID()` with `get_queried_object_id()`

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'wpcf-legislacion-gratis', true ); 
// check if the custom field has a value 
if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) { 
    echo $key_1_value; 
}
```

Comment: Ups, Pieter my bad I just notice that is not in a single, it's in a `sidebar-legislacion.php`, I think in this environment your code will not works, I forgot to mention that on the main post, any advice taking this mistake from me into account?

Comment: Ok, just to be clear then, you need to get the custom field value of the post on a single post page in the sidebar of the single page

Comment: See my update on usage outside the loop