# Performace on 1 million plus meta fields vs 1 field with 1 million multi array

Tags: post-meta

We are potentially looking into building a counter in a post_type. So a post meta field wil be created with some data like total downloads and downloads left (tied to user ID).

We expect up to one million or more users.

My question is, is there a difference in the following to options, does one have a performance gain and/or is there another way to do this. This is all part of our brainstorm and any input is helpful.

Option 1: $user_meta would create a multidimensional array in one meta field.
Option 2: $user_meta_USER_ID would create an array or meta fields.

Example:

```
$user_meta = array(
    'USER_ID' = array(
        'download_count' => INT
        'downloads_left' => INT
    ),
);
```

vs.

```
$user_meta_USER_ID' = array(
    'download_count' => INT
    'downloads_left' => INT
);
```

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167151/31545)

Comment: That information will be serialized.  Any large array will take a long time to serialize and unserialize.  Also if you had one entry per user per post (1 million users time some number of posts) that is a lot of rows; and it will affect WP performance.  I would store that info in a custom table.