# Storing post_meta fields in array

Tags: post-meta

I need to have 8 separate post meta fields on each post in wp-admin (shown in a custom meta field box).

I'd like the data from these 8 fields to be stored in an array as one post_meta field for easy parsing on the front-end.

What's the best way to do this? I have found examples of how to do this via PHP, but not how to combine inputs in the backend on save.

Comment: I would not recommend doing so. Mixing various fields in a serialized array makes a lot of other stuff more difficult later on, e.g. searching for them. Why don't you just build the array from separate values on the frontend?

Comment: @kraftner - These values won't ever need to be searched. Basically I need to allow my editors to include 8 post ID's and custom titles for each of those ID's, so it makes more sense to have the ID's and titles grouped in an array.

Comment: You could think of it as manually including related posts.

Comment: Even more I believe this isn't the right approach. Your blocking a lot of unforeseeable possibilities you may need later on for no particular reason. What is the problem with building the array on the front-end?

Comment: Point taken. I will build it on the frontend instead. Thank you!

Comment: Always a pleasure. :)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167151/31545) if you are worried about performance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with kraftner's comments to the question. This is a bad idea and you stand a good chance of regretting it later. Store you data as granular post meta values. Everything is easier later on.

However, `add_post_meta()` and `save_post_meta()` will serialize objects/arrays for you. You don't have to do anything special:

```
update_post_meta(1,'my_bad_idea',array('i','will','regret','this','later'));
```

And `get_post_meta()` will unserialize it for you:

```
var_dump(get_post_meta(1,'my_bad_idea'));
```

Comment: I know you can send an array of values to update_post_meta. My question was about how best to save the data from many input fields in wp-admin and save those as an array to post_meta.

Comment: It is exactly the same answer -- build an array and save it. I don't understand what is so complicated.