# get_post_custom()

Tags: post-meta

There's very little said about [get_post_custom()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) in codex. I also couldn't find any good explanations or usage from G search. My current understanding is that it gets all the post meta related to the post.

Could someone provide more information? I've prepered few questions to help you out..

---

> Returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a
>   particular post or page.

- What qualifies as *custom field*? Am I right if I say that it's just an alias to post meta?

---

> Note: not only does the function return a multi-dimensional array (ie:
>   always be prepared to deal with an array of arrays, even if expecting
>   array of single values), but it also returns serialized values of any
>   arrays stored as meta values.

- How to *know* if it's array or array of arrays? Is there a safe way to check it automatically *via* code or do I have to check everything manually from database or know by heart?

---

- When should I prefer `get_post_custom()` to `get_post_meta()`? When I need to retrieve/use *most (over 50%)* of the data posts has? What other helpful uses does it serve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What qualifies as custom field?

Yes, a custom field is equal to post metadata, but be aware that some metadata is only for internal use (usually prepended with an underscore, for example `_edit_lock`.

#### A more detailed look at the function

The function `get_post_custom()` is actually just a wrapper for `get_post_meta()`: (`wp-includes/post.php` line 1764), but with the check of the input variable, to ensure a `$post_id` is set.

```
function get_post_custom( $post_id = 0 ) {
        $post_id = absint( $post_id );
        if ( ! $post_id )
                $post_id = get_the_ID();

        return get_post_meta( $post_id );
}
```

which, in return, is just a wrapper for `get_metadata()`.

```
function get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = '', $single = false ) {
    return get_metadata('post', $post_id, $key, $single);
}
```

As the `$key` for the metadata will always be empty, it *always* returns an array from the `$meta_cache`.

### How to know if it's array or array of arrays?

The return will *always* be an array, if no `$key` is set, and this is the case for `get_post_custom()`.

The only thing you have to check is if it is an empty one, or if there are entries:

```
if ( count( $return ) > 0 ) { // whatever you want to do
```

Afterwards you can check, if the desired value is set:

```
if ( isset( $return['yourpostmeta'] ) ) { // whatever you want to do
```

And, to answer your question more directly:

**Every entry in the return array is an array itself**. Even if there is just one value for the key, it will be `$return['yourpostmeta'][0]`. If there are more, they are just added to the array, for example `$return['yourpostmeta'][1]` or `$return['yourpostmeta'][456165]`.

There are a few things to consider:

- If you need only one value, use the `$key` in the function `get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true );`, as you will get a single value, or a *unserialized array* if the data was serialized.
- No entry in the subarray will be serialized.
- You can always use a combination of `isset()` and `foreach()` to loop through the desired keys

This would be an example function for that:

```
if ( isset( $return['yourpostmeta'] ) ) {

    foreach( $return['yourpostmeta'] as $key => $val ) {
    
        echo $val;
    
    }

}
```

### When should I prefer get_post_custom() to get_post_meta()?

You can use `get_post_custom()` in the loop without any arguments, as it defaults the `$post_id` to `get_the_ID()`.

`get_post_meta( $post_id )` is great if you need all the values of a specific post anywhere in your site.

`get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single )` is great for retrieving just one specific custom value.

### Additional resources

Just for interest sake, you should read [@PieterGoosen answer about custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167151/31545) to the following question

- [Custom post meta field effect on the performance on the post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167060/31545)

Comment: Your answer seems more complete than mine, have deleted mine and post my extra info in your answer ;-)

Comment: *Ugh,* I should develop the habit of checking source code.. This is always that one place that I forget to look. Great answer, guys!

Comment: No problem @TwerkingN00b . I did not know the answer straight away by myself, and I really enjoy answering stuff like that, as I learn a lot myself.