# Get random custom-post-type post to display within content

Tags: custom-post-types, the-content

I have a function, within `functions.php` (all code below), that adds an advertisement after `x` amount of paragraphs to any given `single.php` post. I have a custom-post-type called `advertising` that has a Title, Image, and URL field for the advertisement post. In any `single.php` post I have a checkbox to show the ad (true / false) and a number field for the author to choose how many paragraphs to skip before inserting the image advertisement.

**UPDATED CODE:** code below works, however I am unable to get a random post. It keeps pulling the absolute latest post without rotating to the other ones.

```
// http parser
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}

// filter content with ad
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    // checkbox to show ad, default true
    if ( get_field('show_advertisement') ) {
        if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
            // get post-type
            $random_ad = get_posts(array(
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'advertising',
                'order' => 'rand',
                'posts_per_page'=>'1'
            ));
            // get post-type fields
            $random_ad = array_shift($random_ad);
            $link = addhttp( get_field('advertisement_link', $random_ad->ID));
            $image = get_field('upload_advertisement', $random_ad->ID);
            // get html
            $ad_code = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'" /></a>';
            // show ad after # paragraphs
            $show_after = get_field('advertisement_show_after');
            // return appended $content
            return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $show_after, $content );
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    } else {
        return $content;
    }

}

// insert ad into post
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

**EDIT:** SOLVED! Changed `order` to `orderby` and the above code works.

Comment: you say `WP_Query` doesn't work, but I don't see where you've tried to use it.

Comment: because when I tried it broke the website, and I'm unsure how to add `WP_Query` into something usable like `$ad_code`. It's getting a bit over my head at this point.

Comment: Keep in mind that getting random posts is an unexpectedly expensive operation, you would be better picking a random year then querying for that, or randomly picking another search criteria in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, random ordering and searching is quite expensive operations to run, so lets look at how we are going to sort that issue.

Because you only need one post from your custom post type, we only need one random ID which we can pass to `get_post()` in order to get the desired post. Instead of getting the post randomly from the db, we will query all custom post types (*or at least all the post ID's*), save that into a transient, and then we can just pick a random ID from that option.

Lets look at some code: (*This goes into functions.php*)

```
function get_random_id( $post_type = '' )
{
    $q = [];

    // Make sure we have a post type set, check if it exists and sanitize
    $post_type = filter_var( $post_type, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( !$post_type ) 
        return $q;

    if ( !post_type_exists( $post_type ) )
        return $q;

    // The post type exist and is valid, lets continue
    $transient_name = 'rand_ids_' . md5( $post_type );

    // Get the transient, if we have one already
    if ( false === ( $q = get_transient ( $transient_name ) ) ) {
        $args = [ 
            'post_type'      => $post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'fields'         => 'ids', // get only post ID's
            // Add any additional arguments
        ];
        $q = get_posts( $args );

        // Set the transient
        set_transient( $transient_name, $q, 30*DAY_IN_SECONDS );    
    } // endif get_transient

    return $q;
}
```

What we have done, we have now saved all custom post type ids into a transient. This will increase performance by a huge amount. The transient is set for 30 days, so we need to flush and recreate the transient as soon as we publish a new custom post type post.

Lets use the `transition_post_status` action hook: (*This goes into functions.php*)

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    // Make sure we only target our specific post type
    if ( 'advertising' !== $post->post_type )
        return;

    global $wpdb;

    // Delete the transients
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_rand_ids_%')" );
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_rand_ids_%')" );

    // Lets rebuild the transient
    get_random_id( $post->post_type );

}, 10, 3 );
```

All we are left with is to get a random post ID from our `get_random_id()` function and pass that to `get_post()` to get the post object

```
// Get the array of post ID's
$post_type_posts = get_random_id( 'advertising' );
// Make sure we have posts
if ( $post_type_posts ) {
    // Get the post object of the id first in line
    shuffle( $post_type_posts );
    $single_post = get_post( $post_type_posts[0] );
    // Display the post content
}
```

This way you save a lot on resources and is much faster than just simply let SQL choose a random post from the DB

Just as example, your advert injector filter can look something like the following

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    // checkbox to show ad, default true
    if ( get_field('show_advertisement') ) {
        if (     is_single() && 
               ! is_admin() 
        ) {
            // Get the array of post ID's
            $post_type_posts = get_random_id( 'advertising' );
            // Make sure we have posts
            if ( $post_type_posts ) {
                // Get the post object of the id first in line
                shuffle( $post_type_posts );
                $random_ad = get_post( $post_type_posts[0] );

                // Display the post content
                $link = addhttp( get_field('advertisement_link', $random_ad->ID));
                $image = get_field('upload_advertisement', $random_ad->ID);
                // get html
                $ad_code = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'" /></a>';
                // show ad after # paragraphs
                $show_after = get_field('advertisement_show_after');
                // return appended $content
                return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $show_after, $content );

            } 
        }
    } 
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This is highly impressive, and works flawlessly as well. How are you able to check for certain that this function is less expensive (learning)? I have saved this and currently using it, though both answers were correct. Fantastic stuff. This helped me a lot with how I mentally processed this data. Thanks, Pieter!

Comment: What does the `$q` represent, post-type ids? or does it grab all post-type ids regardless of post-type?

Comment: `$q` represents an array of post id's. You can rename it to anything. I just use `$q` for laziness and shorthand ;-). No, `$q` only holds ID's from the post type you pass to the function, in this case `advertising`. For testing benchmark, I usually use [this approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167151/31545)

Comment: You're the man! I highly appreciate this, and that makes sense. All answers work but this is more efficient. Learned a lot through this. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, glad you found this all usefull. Good luck on your project ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First get the random advertising post by `get_posts`

```
$random_ad = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'advertising',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
));
```

Now get the custom fields from this random post

```
if (!empty($random_ad)) {
    $random_ad = array_shift($random_ad);
    $link = addhttp( get_field('advertisement_link', $random_ad->ID));
    $image = get_field('upload_advertisement', $random_ad->ID);
}
```

Build your ad HTML and insert where you want!

```
$ad_code = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'" /></a>';
```

Comment: Of note, `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` internally, also this code doesn't check if `$random_ad` is empty correctly, and should use `if ( !empty( $random_ad ) ) {` instead

Comment: Yes of course but good for getting single post and without setting up post data!

Comment: Code updated...

Comment: Ok, this is good, as I now understand a bulk aspect of what I need to do. However, I'm running into an error, `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string`. [Here's my pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/B0MyEmsk)

Comment: This is because of line number `28`, `$random_ad` should be Ad HTML that is variable `$ad_code`

Comment: Nope, still missing something ... I wish I knew PHP more. Let me try a few things and I'll let you know. I have a feeling your code is getting me close to let me try a few things. The post-type should pull an ad that has those fields already filled out. Just need to get it posted into the content ... hmm.

Comment: @AlexanderGraham Updated my answer please check! `$ad_code` variable should be used in your function `prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, $show_after, $content );` and for pulling a post only if have meta field already filled, you need to add [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) as well!

Comment: @Sumit Updated core code. Ok, I got it, it's working, but it's not pulling random post. It's only pulling latest.

Comment: @Sumit solved! Changed `order` to `orderby`. :) Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Using a random offset might be a faster alternative, than ordering by `RAND()` in the generated SQL query:

```
if( $count = wp_count_posts( 'advertising' )->publish )
{
    $random_ad = get_posts( 
        [
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'offset'            => rand( 0, $count - 1 ),
            'posts_per_page'    => 1,
            'post_type'         => 'advertising'
        ] 
    );
}
```

where we use the `offset` to set the `LIMIT x, 1` SQL part, where `x` depends on the number of posts.

Note that this is might not be so [great](http://devoluk.com/mysql-limit-offset-performance.html) for very large number of rows, but there's also an interesting [benchmark](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nXRHZISDLcOFBLd4D2xUxOzFl7tabTH1jKFZ8bIYBs/edit?hl=en#gid=0) sheet by [Josh Hartman](https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/).

Pieter Goosen has also an interesting approach in his [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218760/26350), that should give you much better alternative than ordering by `RAND()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well! This too makes perfect sense. My only question about anything in this entire thread is what Pieters `$q` was for. I understand everything else for the most part in every answer.

Comment: Regarding the `$q` variable, I guess you mean the array of post ids, you could rename if you prefer,  eg `$post_ids` ?  That "q" could also be a shorthand for "query" @AlexanderGraham

Comment: Correct. I believe it's a catch-all if I read it right.

Comment: Strangely, your code is the slowest of our all on initial testing. Seems like `wp_count_posts()` adds a few extra dollars to the price ;-)

Comment: interesting, thanks for checking it out, I guess it's a good future project to investigate this for various number of rows, e.g. 1k, 10k, 100k, 1m. Such various database sizes should be in the toolbox of every developer - so I definitely need to pimp my dev databases ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: @birgire You have a very good point there. My test install is really really really small, like in 24 posts big with 6 categories and about 40 tags, hahahaha. Where do one get such a large amount of data to make up such huge number of rows ;-)

Comment: it would be handy to have such *.sql available for download for others to play with. Maybe wxr could work for the small sizes and maybe one could generate larger one with e.g. wp-cli. But 1M or 10M might be more difficult to get/generate. Such a WordPress dev db-service should of course have various setups, for various sizes of taxonomies, meta, options etc.  @PieterGoosen