# Is it possible to retrieve posts depending on meta_key LIKE condition?

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query

I'm currently facing a little problem. I'm using ACF plugin which generate complex `meta_key` names when creating hierarchical fields.

I found in my database `meta_key` named `modules_1_content_0_module`.

I want to be able to retrieve all the posts which have a `meta_key` which finish with `_module` and where `meta_value` is a given id.

Is it possible to do that directly with the `WP_Query` API ?

Thanks

Comment: No. You can't do this with WP_Query or Meta_Query.

Comment: Argl... The only solution is to rely on plain SQL ?

Comment: You are right, it's a duplicate, I'll close that question, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting answer on SO which present different methods to resolve that issue: [How do I query for posts by partial meta key?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221760/how-do-i-query-for-posts-by-partial-meta-key)

- [By custom SQL query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/221768/36295) (in my project I've used that solution)
- [By changing the meta schema to store the dynamic `meta_key` as a `meta_value`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/221768/36295)
- [By using the `posts_where` filter to update query behaviour based on input](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/221766/36295)