# Is it possible to set a variable for get_post_meta?

Tags: theme-development, post-meta

I have a lot of places within my templates where I get custom post meta set up with CMB2 and I was wondering if it's possible to set

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID() )
```

to a variable like

```
$service_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() )
```

and then use some sort of shorthand to get my items out of the array?

I've spent some time looking around the internet but haven't managed to find anything so would be great if someone could advice or suggest a better option for outputting my meta data.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? WordPress already cached all meta value for a single post.

Comment: @Sumit - Because otherwise I have to write things like <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cmb_service_icon', true ); ?> for every single bit of meta I want to output. Is that the only way or is there's another way? I'm pretty new to WordPress but come from a Java background so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry I actually do not understand it well. But I can tell you can set array in meta value like `update_post_meta($id, 'key', array(1,2,3));` other thing you can get all the meta value to a variable `get_post_meta( get_the_ID() )` by skipping the key. Please edit your question and explain it a bit more.

Comment: It seems like this is more of a code style question than a specific WP issue. If your goal is to avoid many `get_post_meta()` calls then you could organize them all into one function that you only call once at the top of your template.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for your help, if you could provide an example or link to somewhere showing how to do this in an answer that would be great.

Comment: see [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167151/31545)

Comment: You could write your own template tag as a wrapper function my_echo_meta($metakey) that handles the more unwieldy echo statement.

Comment: My pleasure, and upvoted your answer just because you took the time to post an answer. Just remember to accept your own answer after the 48 hour "ban" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to my question (and in case anyone is interested), this seems to be the best solution:

```
<?php            
   $service_name = $post->_cmb2_service_name;
?>
<p><?php echo $service_name; ?></p>
```